# When using PyQt and setting a style sheet for some widget, how do you find which qss parameters you can change?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtstylesheets

I am setting a style sheet for a slider in Qt (through PyQt) in order to change the handle properties.

After much googling I now know that I need the `QSlider::handle:horizontal` { bunch of different stuff}. However, I only discovered this through googling and patching together bits here and there from multiple pieces of code written in C, CSS, and Python.

I was wondering if there's somewhere I can find all the tags for the things you can change within a style sheet, and how many of them will apply to an individual type such as 'handle'. Changing the handle or a button to be an image isn't a hard thing to do code-wise, but finding the "border-image:" or "image:" tags is arduous.

Comment: What did you Google?  Try ["qt5+style+sheet+reference"](https://www.google.com/search?q=qt5%2Bstyle%2Bsheet%2Breference&oq=qt5%2Bstyle%2Bsheet%2Breference&aqs=chrome..69i57.10155j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

Comment: use https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11165177/qt-qss-tutorials

Answer (score 0):

As eyllanesc mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56649814/when-using-pyqt-and-setting-a-style-sheet-for-some-widget-how-do-you-find-which#comment99878373_56649814), look up the [Qt style sheet introduction](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet.html) and the [Qt style sheet reference](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html).

For your `QSlider` example, you would get

> Supports the box model. For horizontal slides, the min-width and height properties must be provided. For vertical sliders, the min-height and width properties must be provided.
>
> The groove of the slider is styled using the ::groove. The groove is positioned by default in the Contents rectangle of the widget. The thumb of the slider is styled using ::handle subcontrol. The subcontrol moves in the Contents rectangle of the groove subcontrol.
>
> See Customizing QSlider for an example.

And when clicking on the [Customizing QSlider](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-examples.html#customizing-qslider) link, you would see that example

```
QSlider::handle:horizontal {
    background: qlineargradient(x1:0, y1:0, x2:1, y2:1, stop:0 #b4b4b4, stop:1 #8f8f8f);
    border: 1px solid #5c5c5c;
    width: 18px;
    margin: -2px 0; /* handle is placed by default on the contents rect of the groove. Expand outside the groove */
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

And that would give you quite some hints of what is possible.

Also look at the [list of properties](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-properties), [list of property types](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-property-types), [list of pseudo states](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-pseudo-states) and [list of subcontrols](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#list-of-sub-controls).